# scripts being minified in debug mode when not included in @Scripts.Render

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, razor, bundling-and-minification

on an ASP.NET website we have BundleConfig.cs set to minify and concatenate scripts when in Release mode but not when in Debug mode.

In debug mode I have the following sestup
in web.config file.

Then in Proj/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs

the last line is

```
#if DEBUG
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
#else
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif
```

In debug mode the scripts are unminified, so we can debug them, but only when 
using @Scripts.Render in the .cshtml page.

However there are some particular parts of the web application where we load script dynamically for small segments of functionality.

using jQuery.getScript we call the name of the bundle.

For some reason this script is still minified and all debugger; breakpoints are striped out.  Why is this?

The only way around this is to do the following.

```
#if DEBUG
// Iterate over each bundle ()   *not needed if compilation debug="true"
foreach (var bundle in bundles)
{
    // And strip out any transformations (minify)
    bundle.Transforms.Clear();
}
#endif
```

this seems unnecessary and I don't know why this doesn't work without this.

Comment: Isn't this related to browser cache? Did you check the browser debug console if the request result is really coming from the server?

Comment: `@Scripts.Render ` (I think) is only generating the appropriate HTML, so it shouldn't make a difference if jQuery fetches them or the browser from the script tags. Check the request log in the browser debug console (for example in Chrome), there you can see what is the difference when the browser loads them via script tags, and when jQuery fetches the same.